# Combine Jcarousel with a Swipe Gesture such as JQtouch/sencha/etc

Tags: jquery, jcarousel, gesture, swipe

I'm wondering if anyone has combined Jcarousel with a swipe gesture so you can scroll through images on iOS/mobile.

I am continuing to search for an answer and will post it once I find it but would be grateful for the collaboration if you have suggestions. Thanks in advance!

Goal:
- swipe-able in mobile devices
- ability to still click/tap the image to go to the thumbnail's destination

My current starting point: Jcarousel: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_auto.html

Comment: Update: hoping to combine Jquery Swipe by Ryan Scherf with Jcarousel: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/swipe Hope to have a solution soon once I make time to test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not exactly like Jcarousel, I have gone with [this](http://flex.madebymufffin.com/) as a better alternative and works great as a slideshow for desktop and swipeable for touch devices. Hope this helps others.

http://flex.madebymufffin.com/

Comment: this doesnt have swipe feature